# How to make two JOIN's for same table name in MySql?

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table2.bonus table3.shift, table3.endtime, table4.vacation
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.endtime = table3.endtime
INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.userid = table4.userid 
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
```

this throws error: `Not unique table/alias: 'table3'`

i tried

```
INNER JOIN table3 tbl3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
    INNER JOIN tbl3 ON table2.endtime = tbl3.endtime
```

sill not working

Answer (score 2):

Give it a unique alias:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table2.bonus t3a.shift, t3b.endtime, table4.vacation
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
INNER JOIN table3 t3a ON table2.userid = t3a.userid
INNER JOIN table3 t3b ON table2.endtime = t3b.endtime
INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.userid = table4.userid 
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position;
```

Actually, it makes for neater code to give *every* table an alias:

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    t2.wage,
    t2.bonus,
    t3a.shift,
    t3b.endtime,
    t4.vacation
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
INNER JOIN table3 t3a ON t2.userid = t3a.userid
INNER JOIN table3 t3b ON t2.endtime = t3b.endtime
INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t4.userid = t1.userid 
LEFT JOIN table5 t5 ON t1.name = t5.position;
```

It looks like you have an error in your join for table4, and a missing comma in the selects - I have corrected it in this last version.

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing the table names:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2
ON t1.X = t2.Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias with the keyword `AS` (which can be omitted).

```
INNER JOIN table3 AS t31 ON table2.userid = t31.userid
INNER JOIN table3 AS t32 ON table2.endtime = t32.endtime
```